# mapping classes nested within another class using fluent nhibernate automapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

How to map a class that has another class nested inside it. I am using automapping. It gives exception 'NHibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: class1+class2'

suppose you have

```
public class baseclass
{

} 

public class class1 : baseclass
{

  public class class2 : baseclass
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues is fixed the repo. You may view this post on fluent support page..

http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/288-map-a-class-that-has-another-class-nested-inside-using-automapping